# Countif across multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count the number of instances where reference is 'a' and B2:D12 has a value > 0.  So for 'a', there are 8 instances where a residual value > 0.

When using the `countif` formula, I get the error `Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size`.

I believe I need to either use ArrayFormula or split the residual parts to simplify the formula.
The formula I tried is `countifs(A2:A12,"a",B2:D12,">0")`

| ref | residual 1 | residual 2 | residual 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| b | 2 | 1 |  |
| c | 1.5 |  |  |
| d | 2.67 | 0.89 |  |
| a | 1.88 |  | 3.75 |
| b | 3.2 | 1.6 | 1.07 |
| a | 2.19 |  |  |
| b | 3.66 | 1.83 | 1.22 |
| c |  |  |  |
| a |  | 2.04 | 1.36 |
| d |  |  | 8.13 |

I can get the sum of the various parts using `ArrayFormula(sumif($A$2:$A$15,"a",(B$2:D$15)))` but cannot get the count.

Comment: `=countifs(A2:A12,"a",ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B12+C2:C12+D2:D12),">0")`
Is this the result you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for looking, but nope.  I was trying to get a count of 8 as there are 8 times that an entry in B12:D12 > 0 and has a reference of 'a'

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your question to include that information, as it was not clear what you meant originally. I'm going to write an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNTIFS` does not work in your first example, because you have two arrays of different sizes. `A2:A12` has 1 column while `B2:D12` has 3 columns. You can sum them as suggested by David Dykstra's answer, but that becomes hard to update manually if instead of 3 columns you have 300.

**You can use SUMPRODUCT:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A12="a")*--(B2:D12>0))
```

As specified in the comments, this returns the result 8 for the example.

Comment: Many thanks for that Irene - around 50 columns on my workbook.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

=countifs(A2:A12,"a",B2:B12,">0")+countifs(A2:A12,"a",C2:C12,">0")+countifs(A2:A12,"a",D2:D12,">0")

Comment: Thanks David.  I did wonder if it would need to get broken down to separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((A2:A12="a")*(B2:D12>0))
```

Sometimes it's easier to just work with Booleans like they're arrays of 0s and 1s.